# OpenWRT making dns changes permanent

Tags: networking, openwrt

I am currently working on a openWRT system. I want to change the dns addresses and add multiple addresses if possible. In order to do that i need to change `resolv.conf` file but in this case I don't know which `resolv.conf` file is going to help me.

Contents of `/etc/config/dhcp`:

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option filterwin2k '0'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option nonegcache '0'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option localservice '1'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
```

According to this file do i need to integrate my changes to resolv.conf.auto file ? And if i do that , next time i reboot the changes will be gone for good. If that's my solution then i want to make these changes permanent.

Inside of /tmp/resolv.conf.auto

```
# Interface wan2
nameserver 192.168.137.1
search mshome.net
```

Wan2 is my interface that i created before.
Say , i want to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` to this file. How can i achieve that with permanent solution ?

Comment: That file is in /tmp, it is not probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [dnsmasq docs](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dhcp.dnsmasq) and [dhcp docs](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration) for all the options. Personally, I would prefer to forward DNS requests to your preferred servers. Here's an example of configuring this with uci

```
uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[-1].server=8.8.8.8
uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[-1].server=8.8.4.4
uci commit dhcp
```

Otherwise, you can remove the resolvfile option and make your changes in /etc/resolv.conf (ensure that it's not a symlink)

Comment: Thank you , i did it like this after i posted this question. Your answer is true.